# node.js / express - stream every nth word in a binary file

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

If I want to transmit an entire binary file, I can do something simple like:

```
res.sendfile(file);
```

I could also open a stream and do it a little more manually:

```
var stream = require('fs').createReadStream(file);
stream.pipe(res);
```

I'm at a loss to find a way to send only part of a (really big) file.  In my particular case, I have a binary file of interleaved int16s and I would like to be able to separate out one set of data from the rest.  I.e., if I want the 5th set of data in the file, I need to:

1. open the file
2. seek over the first 8 bytes
3. until reaching the end of the file:

   3a. -read/send two bytes

   3b. -seek 2 bytes times the number of sets of data in the file (less one) to the next set of two bytes (let's say there are 16 sets of data in the file -> seek 30 bytes)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I would go for reading the file as [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readint16be_offset_noassert) and reading the data you need, playing with offsets and read block sizes.

Comment: My (perhaps poor) attempts to do it this way have been slower than just sending over the entire (300MB-1GB) file.  I'm hoping someone has some sort of fancy Transform / Stream / pipe code handy!